# How do I read ragged/implied do data into r

Tags: r

How do I read data like the example below?   (My actual files are like ftp://ftp.aoml.noaa.gov/hrd/pub/hwind/Operational/2012/AL182012/1030/0730/AL182012_1030_0730.gz formatted per http://www.aoml.noaa.gov/hrd/Storm_pages/grid.html -- They look like fortran implied-do writes)

The issue I have is that there are multiple headers and vectors within the file having differing numbers of values per line. Scan seems to start from the beginning for .gz files, while I want the reads to parse incrementally through the file.

```
This is a headerline with a name.  
The fourth line has the number of elements in the first vector,
and the next vector is encoded similarly
7
1 2 3
4 5 6
7
8
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8
```

This doesn't work as I'd like:

```
fh<-gzfile("junk.gz")
headers<-readLines(fh,3)
nx<-as.numeric(readLines,1)
x<-scan(fh,nx) 
ny<-as.numeric(readLines,1)
y<-scan(fh,ny)
```

This sort of works, but I have to then calculate the skip values:

```
...
x<-scan(fh,skip=3,nx)
...
```

Ah... I discovered that using the gzfile() to open does not allow seek operations on the data, so the scan()s all rewind and start at the beginning of the file.    If I unzip the file and operate on the uncompressed data, I can read the various bits incrementally with readLines(fh,n) and scan(fh,n=n)

```
readVector<-function(fh,skip=0,what=double()){ 
  if (skip !=0 ){junk<-readLines(fh,skip)}
  n<-scan(fh,1)
  scan(fh,what=what,n=n)
}

fh<-file("junk")
headers<-readLines(fh,3)
x<-readVector(fh) 
y<-readVector(fh)
xl<-readVector(fh) 
yl<-readVector(fh) 
...  # still need to process a parenthesized complex array, but that is a different problem.
```

Comment: What structure do you want the data to have when you're done?

Comment: The file that you actually linked to seems to have more than one type of data. "Surface wind components" are identified differently (seems like pairs of numbers within brackets). What data do you actually want, what final format are you looking for, and are all the files structured more or less the same?

Comment: Sorry. Didn't see your edit. It might also be possible to do something with `grep` to help with the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at a few sample files, it looks like you only need to determine the number to be read once, and that can be used for processing all parts of the file.

As I mentioned in a comment, `grep` would be useful for helping automate the process. Here's a quick function I came up with:

```
ReadFunky <- function(myFile) {
  fh <- gzfile(myFile)
  myFile <- readLines(fh)
  vecLen <- as.numeric(myFile[5])
  startAt <- grep(paste("^\\s+", vecLen), myFile)
  T1 <- lapply(startAt[-5], function(x) {
    scan(fh, n = vecLen, skip = x)
  })
  T2 <- gsub("\\(|\\)", "", 
             unlist(strsplit(myFile[(startAt[5]+1):length(myFile)], ")(", 
                             fixed = TRUE)))
  T2 <- read.csv(text = T2, header = FALSE)
  T2 <- split(T2, rep(1:vecLen, each = vecLen))
  T1[[5]] <- T2
  names(T1) <- myFile[startAt-1]
  T1
}
```

You can apply it to a downloaded file. Just replace with the actual path to where you downloaded the file.

```
temp <- ReadFunky("~/Downloads/AL182012_1030_0730.gz")
```

The function returns a `list`. The first four items in the list are the vectors of coordinates.

```
str(temp[1:4])
# List of 4
#  $ MERCATOR X COORDINATES ... KILOMETERS : num [1:159] -476 -470 -464 -458 -452 ...
#  $ MERCATOR Y COORDINATES ... KILOMETERS : num [1:159] -476 -470 -464 -458 -452 ...
#  $ EAST LONGITUDE COORDINATES ... DEGREES: num [1:159] -81.1 -81 -80.9 -80.9 -80.8 ...
#  $ NORTH LATITUDE COORDINATES ... DEGREES: num [1:159] 36.2 36.3 36.3 36.4 36.4 ...
```

The fifth item is a set of 2-column `data.frame`s that contain the data from your "parenthesized complex array". Not really sure what the best structure for this data was, so I just stuck it in `data.frame`s. You'll get as many `data.frame`s as the expected number of values for the given data set (in this case, 159).

```
length(temp[[5]])
# [1] 159
str(temp[[5]][1:4])
# List of 4
# $ 1:'data.frame':  159 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ V1: num [1:159] 7.59 7.6 7.59 7.59 7.58 ...
#   ..$ V2: num [1:159] -1.33 -1.28 -1.22 -1.16 -1.1 ...
# $ 2:'data.frame': 159 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ V1: num [1:159] 7.66 7.66 7.65 7.65 7.64 ...
#   ..$ V2: num [1:159] -1.29 -1.24 -1.19 -1.13 -1.07 ...
# $ 3:'data.frame': 159 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ V1: num [1:159] 7.73 7.72 7.72 7.71 7.7 ...
#   ..$ V2: num [1:159] -1.26 -1.21 -1.15 -1.1 -1.04 ...
# $ 4:'data.frame': 159 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ V1: num [1:159] 7.8 7.8 7.79 7.78 7.76 ...
#   ..$ V2: num [1:159] -1.22 -1.17 -1.12 -1.06 -1.01 ...
```

---

#### Update

If you want to modify the function so you can read directly from the FTP url, change the first two lines to read as the following and continue from the "myFile" line:

```
ReadFunky <- function(myFile, fromURL = TRUE) {
  if (isTRUE(fromURL)) {
    x <- strsplit(myFile, "/")[[1]]
    y <- download.file(myFile, destfile = x[length(x)])
    fh <- gzfile(x[length(x)])
  } else {
    fh <- gzfile(myFile)
  }
```

Usage would be like: `temp <- ReadFunky("ftp://ftp.aoml.noaa.gov/hrd/pub/hwind/Operational/2012/AL182012/1023/1330/AL182012_1023_1330.gz")` for a file that you are going to download directly, and `temp <- ReadFunky("~/AL182012_1023_1330.gz", fromURL=FALSE)` for a file that you already have saved on your system.